# Searchable Activity is not called

Tags: android, search, searchview

I am trying to implement WhatsApp like Search in my application.I have to implement the following screen :

[image: ScreenShot]

As you can see in the screenshot,I have a search icon as option menu .

**XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

On clicking search icon search view will be opened .

**CODE:**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_friend_list_activity, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) FriendsListActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            if (item != null) {
                searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
            }
            if (searchView != null) {
                searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(FriendsListActivity.this.getComponentName()));
                searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                        Log.e("Query",query);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.FriendsListActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.WelcomeActivity">
        <!-- To display the search view-->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.SearchResultsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"
                android:launchMode="singleTop" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

You can see here i have searchable activity named SearchResultsActivity. 
I am following [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) tutorial.

**SearchResultsACtivity:**

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.e("onCreate","in SerachActivity called");
    handleIntent(getIntent());
 }

 @Override
 protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    handleIntent(intent);
 }

 private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        Log.e("Query1",query);
        //use the query to search your data somehow
       }
    }
 }
```

I think i am doing something wrong here.When i am trying to search ,SearchResultsActivity is not called .Please help me how can i implement search as WhatsApp do?

Comment: Because you are never starting the SearchResultsActivity?

Comment: you can also use TextWatcher for it

Comment: @MuratK. : According to the documentation "A searchable activity is the Activity in your application that performs searches based on a query string and presents the search results.

When the user executes a search in the search dialog or widget, the system starts your searchable activity and delivers it the search query in an Intent with the ACTION_SEARCH action. Your searchable activity retrieves the query from the intent's QUERY extra, then searches your data and presents the results."

Comment: Maybe add the meta data `android.app.searchable` inside the search activity branch.

Comment: @MuratK. Still not working for me

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're reading the android tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html), that page is very confusing if not completely wrong. There're two places went wrong in your code.

1. When you call `searchView#setSearchableInfo`, you're telling Android what activity to launch to handle search result, in your case SearchResultsActivity. So you can't set component name to FriendsListActivity, instead change it to `SearchResultsActivity.searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this, SearchResultsActivity.class)))`
2. In order for an activity to become a searchable that's able to be found by searchManager, you need to add the `android.app.searchable` meta-data label to the Activity block in your manifest. Note this label should **NOT** be added to the activity you display the SearchView, the tutorial page totally states it wrong. So change your SearchResultsActivity to the following.

If you made these two changes, your SearchView from FriendsListActivity would correctly holds a [mSearchable](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/widget/SearchView.java#1089) instance that's able to start SearchResultsAcitivity. Otherwise it will be null.

```
<activity android:name=".activity.SearchResultsActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have wrote like this: (so you passed FriendsListActivity instead of SearchResult Activity):

```
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(FriendsListActivity.this.getComponentName()));
```

but you should pass the componentName like this:

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(FriendsListActivity.this , SearchResultsActivity.class);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName));
```